# Do I need to convert an old Access Database, and if so how?

Tags: microsoft-access

I have an Access 2003 database. When I click on a pivot table, I get this message

```
MS Access There isn't enough memory to complete the 
Automation object operation on the worksheet object.
```

There is a lot of discussion concerning this message. Here is one [link](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/113228-access-2003-file-pivot-table-issue-when-opening-in-access-2010]).  This [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/i-just-installed-office-2010-and-i-am-getting-an/d1de14dd-3582-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5) has even more detail.

But this particular link's explanation doesn't really go into fixing the problem in general, like fixing the pivot tables and getting things all nicely back together in the original Access database. That's why I am also interested in converting the database to 2010 format if that is possible.

Are there instructions (I cannot currently find them and would very much appreciate a link) on dealing with this problem in a nice stepwise fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether converting will fix this particular issue or not, but it can't hurt to try. Just make a backup of the .MDB, then open the copy in Access 2010 and Save As the new .ACCDB format. That should do it and you can then see if your problem is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It opens with Access 2010, but I have no option to save in the .accdb format.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: After you open the DB, isn't there an option under the File menu for **Save and Publish**?

Comment: You can also do the Shrink and Repair option, which automatically upgrades it.

Comment: The default option is to save it in the new format if you use `save as` of course.  You can only change the format if you do `save as` and look for the drop down box to change the extension.

Comment: Did, and the option to save in the new format isn't there. Only .mdb offered.